# I want to sort index in Lucene.net how I can make descending of this one in c#?

Tags: c#, sorting, lucene.net

I have the code for sorting results from Lucene.net, but I need this search result sorted in descending order:

```
var sort = new Lucene.Net.Search.Sort(
    new Lucene.Net.Search.SortField("date", Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.LONG));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lucene.Net.Search.Sort constructor has an overload to reverse sorting order :

```
var sort = new Lucene.Net.Search.Sort(
    new Lucene.Net.Search.SortField("date", Lucene.Net.Search.SortField.LONG),
    true);
```

From : http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#sbnThrht2Bk/trunk/Lucene.Net/Search/Sort.cs&q=Lucene.Net.Search.Sort&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Comment: thanks dear but same code i already apply and problem is alredy solved.